# Change Row Color in PHP data table by Date

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```
Today : <?php echo date("m/d/Y"); ?>
<ph>ISSUED BOOKS | DUE BOOKS</ph>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="tblissued">
      <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <th height="39">id</th>
        <th>Officer</th>
        <th>Member_ID</th>
        <th>Book_ID</th>
        <th>Issued_date</th>
        <th>Due_date</th>
        <th>Remarks</th>
      </tr>
      <?php do { ?>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td height="33"><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Officer']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Member_ID']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Book_ID']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Issued_date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Due_date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Remarks']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_rsissuedbooks = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsissuedbooks)); ?>
    </table>
```

i want to color the rows Due_date if due_date is greater than today (php 1st line in code)
im not good in english..
sorry for that, i hope you will understand..

Comment: what do you want to color ? the full row, the full column or a cell ?

Comment: hmmm... the full row bgcolor is good i think.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work.

```
  <?php do {
  $style = "";
  if ($row_rsissuedbooks['Due_date'] > date("m/d/Y")){
    $style = "style='background:#FF0000;'";
  }
  ?>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <td height="33"><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Officer']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Member_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Book_ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Issued_date']; ?></td>
      <td <?php echo $style;?>><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Due_date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Remarks']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_rsissuedbooks = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsissuedbooks)); ?>
```

Comment: If you want it to be the whole row, just move `<?php echo $style;?>` to the tr element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Issued_date']; ?></td>
<?php
    echo "<td";
    if(strtotime($row_rsissuedbooks['Due_date'])>time())
    {
        echo " style=\"background-color:#00FF00\"";
    }
    echo ">".$row_rsissuedbooks['Due_date']."</td>";
?>
<td><?php echo $row_rsissuedbooks['Remarks']; ?></td>
```